# I am a boy in my 20's. I m very thin and want to increase body fat ..?

Tags: body-fat

Please suggest me how do I can increase my body fat.?

Comment: I think you may be mistaking muscle mass with body fat.  I'd guess that you want to increase your overall muscle mass and **not** body fat.  If that's the case, please re-word your question to indicate that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes no mention of fitness.